# Sharing SSH Tunnel

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, internet

I'm connecting my VPS via SSH. I'm using this command while I'm connecting to server:

ssh -D local-ip:3232 -p 22 user@server-ip

So, I can connect my server via SSH and connect to internet via SSH tunnel. I'm doing it with my wlan device. Also, I want share my SSH tunnel with local network on eth device.

How I can share my ssh tunnel to local network?

Answer (score 0):

If you're already specifying `-D 1.2.3.4:1080`, you're all set. Barring any `iptables` rules, your SOCKS proxy will be reachable from other computers. If you want your proxy to be reachable from the wired network, `1.2.3.4` must be replaced with your wired IP address.

`-p 22` is redundant, by the way. Port 22 is already the default SSH port.

Comment: I set 1.2.3.4:1080 as proxy connection in a local pc, and tested a connection on Chrome, but output is ERR_EMPTY_RESPONS: No data couldn't be retrieved.

Comment: Just to make sure, you replaced `1.2.3.4` with your actual IP address, right? To see more about what's going in, start `ssh` in verbose mode and with `-N` (no remote shell). If you require further information, please update your question.